# How do I extract the values from the string i.e a syntax tree?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am working on the movies dataset and a column for Genres has a very complicated format. It is of type Object with an **embedded dictionary**. The format looks like JSON format. SO the genres column is a series of json values .A typical value in the first 2 cells are as follows:

**Cell1:**    '[{"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 14, "name": "Fantasy"}, {"id": 28, "name": "Action"}]'
**Cell2:**    '[{"id": 28, "name": "Action"}, {"id": 12, "name": "Adventure"}, {"id": 80, "name": "Crime"}]'

Now I want to extract these genres i.e values for the key **name** into a list. For eg: the first cell should contain [Adventre,Fantasy,Action]
second cell should contain [Action,Adventure,Crime]

I tried with some string methods, but it didn't work. I also read about the library **ast**, but I have no idea about the same. How do I achieve the above result??

Thanks

Comment: um, that looks like JSON. What are you talking about with regards to "columns" and "type Object"??? What is a "cell?" Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga actually it's a part of a pandas dataframe.

Comment: OK, then what does that have to do with abstract-syntax trees? I think you are asking *how to parse JSON*.

Comment: if this isn't customer facing, and you can trust all input, I think you're looking for `eval`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The Json thing is converting the entire thing to a list. However I just want values from the **name** key inside the dictionary.